# What is a main and background threads in iOS?

Tags: swift

can you guys explain what a background and main threads are? 
I'm a junior iOS Developer(swift) and I've been programming for 6 month and never heard of this before.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Threads allow you to execute multiple code paths concurrently inside a single application.

iOS apps have a main thread which processes all the UI logic and base of your app. Sometimes you need to push your heavy code (such as a network call) to a different (background) thread so it doesn't clog up the main thread and block your UI from changing for example. It also allows you to do multiple things at one, or run multiple network calls.

This article explains in more detail:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH1-SW1